# DateTime::setTime() expects parameter 1 to be int, string given, but disapear when trying to be observed

Tags: php, datetime

I have this following piece of code in php7.4 , to create a date from an other

```
    $date = clone $regularCourse->getNextCronExecutionDate();
    $date->modify('+ 3 days');
    $date->setTime($date->format('H'), $date->format('i'), 0, 0);
```

I've tested it locally and in production, and it used to work fine. And suddenly it started to fail. with the error

```
DateTime::setTime() expects parameter 1 to be int, string given
```

and it failed rather regularly and predictably because my sentry gave me 4000 occurence of the event (it's a cron task that runs every minutes, and sentry show me the error has happened 60 times every hours for the last days)

BUT !

Now that i've added some debug in order to display the value, it does not fail anymore
The code I've used

```
     // Added to debug some courses failing
     ob_start();
     var_dump($date);
     $dumped_message= ob_get_clean();

     \Sentry\addBreadcrumb(
         new \Sentry\Breadcrumb(
             \Sentry\Breadcrumb::LEVEL_INFO,
             \Sentry\Breadcrumb::TYPE_DEFAULT,
             'error_reporting',
             "course Id " . $regularCourse->getId()
         )
     );
     \Sentry\addBreadcrumb(
         new \Sentry\Breadcrumb(
             \Sentry\Breadcrumb::LEVEL_INFO,
             \Sentry\Breadcrumb::TYPE_DEFAULT,
             'error_reporting',
             $dumped_message
         )
     );
```

I don't know if var_dump-ing the variable produce some side effect ?

so my questions

1. when does this error happen ?
2. why my debug code make the issue disapear ?

Comment: Could it be that your environment needs an update? Sometimes old environments have weird bugs like this, for instance old XAMPP environments.

Comment: Aside from `declare(strict_types=1)`, I can't think of any scenario that can trigger that error without having an earlier fatal error, nor do I understand the role of breadcrumbs in debugging. But if that's actually the full error message perhaps you have an error handler that swallowing information.

Comment: It looks like strict types have been enabled as in @ÁlvaroGonzález comment. Perhaps inside the `Sentry` code they are then disabled? The workaround is to cast to `int`: `$date->setTime((int)$date->format('H'), (int)$date->format('i'), 0, 0);`

Comment: @Martin i'm deploying on heroku, so it's the latest 7.4.7

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález , ah yes you're right the previous commit was to add (among other things) , a declare(strict_types=1) ,  for the breadcrumb the goal is to see the variable value in Sentry as it's production code. so now indeed it makes much more sense :)

Comment: @Nick , yes  I didn't see in the meantime somebody added the cast (it's a collaborative project ^^) so actually the debugging code had nothing to do about it.

Comment: @allan.simon ah, the joys of collaboration! I'm glad you've got it sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `declare(strict_types=1)` you need to be careful about types:

- [DateTime::setTime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settime.php) expects integers:

  ```
  public DateTime::setTime ( int $hour , int $minute [, int $second = 0 [, int $microseconds = 0 ]] ) : DateTime
  ```
- [DateTime::format()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) returns strings:

  ```
  public DateTime::format ( string $format ) : string
  ```

In this case you can just cast to int, though that can easily mask other format errors:

```
declare(strict_types=1);
$date = new \DateTime();
// Correct
$date->setTime((int)$date->format('H'), (int)$date->format('i'), 0, 0);
// Typo, no error thrown becuase `Sunday` casts to 0
$date->setTime((int)$date->format('l'), (int)$date->format('i'), 0, 0);
```

... while

```
$date = new \DateTime();
$date->setTime($date->format('l'), $date->format('i'), 0, 0);
// DateTime::setTime() expects parameter 1 to be int, string given
```

Comment: yes, I think if you precise that in that case you need to do an explicit (int), this answer is then perfectly spot on :)

Comment: damn, so without resorting to more complex solution , it seems you can't have have both type checking and strict  string->int conversion :(